# Can someone help me to achieve this result in Photoshop Cs6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]I want  to make this buttons too look shiny like in the image[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to work for everything individually.

For the Red circle:

- Either add a gradient
- Or add solid color, select half the circle, **add feather**, take a brush & a lighter color, opacity < 25% and **on a new layer** apply brush.

[image: Half circle]

- Something like this ^
- **Duplicate this layer (ctrl + j)**

  - Then go to layer Style => Bevel and Emboss =>
  - Click on Gloss Contour image, and make the graph like given below. (Play around and see the effects)

[image: Contour Graph]

- Keep Highlight and shadow mode to normal for first
- Playing around with and **altitude, angle, opacity, depth and size** will give you desired effect.

[image: Final]

I added two half circles with low opacity brush (first step).

Answer (score 0):

One way I can suggest is:
If the image is flattened, separate the elements into layers as yellow triangle, and red circle .
Then apply [This Style](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17VGrLYpsfar6F1SBrzfnMsh5RQUIANM_) to each layer via styles panel (add it to styles list by double-clicking file). I tried to made it as near as it looks in reference image. It contents "Gradient Color" and "Emboss and Bevel" effects. change them at your choice in "Layer style" options dialog (bring it via double-clicking layer at layers panel).
Hope it comin' handy.